# Prevent element from animating based on previous class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.example').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css('background','red');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).css('background','yellow');
  }
);

$('.test').click(function(){
    $(this).css('marginTop','+=20px').removeClass('example');
  }
);

<div class="text example"></div>
```

Although the class `example` was seemingly removed, the `hover` actions for it are still being applied to the element that once had that class. How can I prevent this?

http://jsfiddle.net/gSfc3/

Here it is in jsFiddle. As you can see, after executing the `click` function to remove the class, the background still changes on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers are bound to a *Node*, so it doesn't matter if that Node doesn't own a specific className anymore. You would need to `.unbind()` those events manually, or better, use jQuerys `.off()` method.

So, if you can be sure that there aren't any other event handlers bound to that node, just call

```
$(this).css('marginTop','+=20px').removeClass('example').off();
```

This will remove **any** event handler from that Node. If you need to be specific, you can use jQuerys *Event namespacing*, like so

```
$('.example').on( 'mouseenter.myNamespace'
   function () {
       $(this).css('background','red');
   }
).on('mouseleave.myNamespace'
   function() {
       $(this).css('background','yellow');
   }
);
```

and use this call to only unbind any event that is within the namespace `.myNamespace`

```
$(this).css('marginTop','+=20px').removeClass('example').off('.myNamespace');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.example').unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave')`

In your code, `$('.example').hover` attaches a mouseenter and mouseleave directly to each element.

-or-

A better solution might be to use delegation with `on`

```
$(document.body).on('mouseenter', '.example', function() { ... });
$(document.body).on('mouseleave', '.example', function() { ... });
```

Using that code, removing the `example` class will work as expected, because the handlers are based on css selector, while `.hover` attaches directly to the elements.

Comment: Or just .unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.example').live({
    mouseenter:function () {
        $(this).css('background','red');
    },
    mouseleave:function () {
        $(this).css('background','yellow');
    }
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gSfc3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.test').hover(
    function () {
        $('.example').css('background','red');
    },
    function () {
        $('.example').css('background','yellow');
    }
);
```